# PHP - trying to remove blank lines generated in my program

Tags: php, null, lines

I'm not too experienced in php but have to modify a program and a very small part of it is to remove lines where values are being set to blank or '' null values.  Here is the little code snipplet:

```
  echo "\t\tfor(index=0; index < $maxclothrows; index++)\n";
  echo "\t\t{\n";    
  echo "\t\t\tdocument.pickDivision.cloth.options[index].text = '';\n";
  echo "\t\t\tdocument.pickDivision.cloth.options[index].value = '';\n";
  echo "\t\t}\n\n";'
```

This above code is used to set some values to '', but then after I would like those blank values removed rather then showing up in the list because when I scroll down you have a whole bunch of blank lines.  How can I remove these completely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this for a generated javascript file? also look into using [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax so you dont have to have so many echos

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after your code:

```
echo "\t\tfor (var i in document.pickDivision.cloth.options) {\n\n";
echo "\t\tvar option = document.pickDivision.cloth.options[i];\n\n";
echo "\t\tif (option.value == '') {\n\n";
echo "\t\tdocument.pickDivision.cloth.options[i] = null;\n\n";
echo "\t\t}\n\n";
echo "\t\t}\n\n";
```

Or try replacing your own function with this:

```
  echo "\t\tfor(index=0; index < $maxclothrows; index++)\n";
  echo "\t\t{\n";    
  echo "\t\t\tdocument.pickDivision.cloth.options[index] = null;\n";
  echo "\t\t}\n\n";'
```

Comment: Thanks Emilian, I tried to add the code you wrote above after my own and it actually ended up removing all the lines, even the ones that weren't blank.  But I can still select those blank lines also.  I want to have it so I can't select the blank lines and that they can't be seen.

Comment: Darn...still no luck.  It is still giving me blanks (nulls).  Is there a way I can wrap a function around the part where I have?                                                               echo "\t\t\tdocument.pickDivision.cloth.options[index].text = '';\n";  Or maybe some line right after it?

Comment: OK, see updated answer. Hope that works :) Also, are you getting any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks Emilian, I was actually excited because I didn't see blank lines, but the problem is that there are options a and b when, a is selected then lets say 20 items are selected, when b is chosen then 10 items are selected.  But when b is selected then the extra 10 items that option a had are also displayed.  My function actually makes those extra 10 items into ' '.  But then I would like to have those ' ' removed.  Your code did remove the ' ' but then kept the extra 10 items.  Hope that made sense?